# How to make Mantine burger close after link is selected?

Tags: javascript, next.js, hamburger-menu, mantine

I want to make the Mantine [burger](https://mantine.dev/core/burger/) auto close after a nav choice is selected in the modal. It seems as if it is not possible for the Mantine burger to automatically close (because the x icon stays). I am using NextJS with Mantine & react-icons.

```
    export default function HeaderMiddle({ links }: HeaderMiddleProps) {
      const { colorScheme, toggleColorScheme } = useMantineColorScheme();
      const dark = colorScheme === 'dark';

      const [opened, { toggle, open, close }] = useDisclosure(false, {
        onOpen: () => burgerClick(),
        onClose: () => closeAllModals(),
      });
      const [active, setActive] = useState(links[0].link);
      const { classes, cx } = useStyles();

      const items = links.map((link) => (
        <a
          key={link.label}
          href={link.link}
          className={cx(classes.link, {
            [classes.linkActive]: active === link.link,
          })}
          onClick={(event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            setActive(link.link);
          }}
        >
          {link.label}
        </a>
      ));

      const burgerItems = links.map((link) => (
        <a
          key={link.label}
          href={link.link}
          className={cx(classes.link, {
            [classes.linkActive]: active === link.link,
          })}
          onClick={(event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            setActive(link.link);
            closeAllModals();
          }}
        >
          {link.label}
        </a>
      ));

      const burgerClick = () => {
        openModal({
          title: 'Subscribe to newsletter',
          children: <>{burgerItems}</>,
        });
      };

      return (
        <Header height={56} mb={120}>
          <Container className={classes.inner}>
            <Burger
              opened={opened}
              onClick={toggle}
              size="sm"
              className={classes.burger}
            />
            <Group className={classes.links} spacing={5}>
              {items}
            </Group>

            {/* <MantineLogo size={28} /> */}

            <Group spacing={0} className={classes.social} position="right" noWrap>
              ...
            </Group>
          </Container>
        </Header>
      );
    }
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

next: 12.1.5
@mantine/core: 4.2.12

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the link call ***close*** method of useDisclosure, it will make opened to false. Burger state is depend on opened so, it wil close the burger on false.

```
const burgerItems = links.map((link) => (
    <a
      key={link.label}
      href={link.link}
      className={cx(classes.link, {
        [classes.linkActive]: active === link.link,
      })}
      onClick={(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setActive(link.link);
        closeAllModals();
        // It will set opened to false (so it will close Burger)
        close()
      }}
    >
      {link.label}
    </a>
  ));
```

Comment: I have already tried this and it does not work.

Comment: Code in the question doesn't have close method called in burgerItems

Answer (score 0):

I found something that might help you
On the [Mantine Doc](https://ui.mantine.dev/category/headers), one header called '***Responsive header***' is working fine after you clicked on any of the burger items.

Simply follow the codes and should be fine!